# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'pk' with Django Rest Framework while adding item to a many to many relationship

Tags: django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-serializer

First question here, so please bear with me. I'm learning Django and the Django Rest Framework, and I'm getting an exception when adding a related object in a many to many relationship. What I do not understand is that the object gets created correctly, and I am getting the error when getting the response.

This is an excerpt of my urls.py:

```
    path('mybox/', views_api.MyBoxList.as_view(), name='mybox-list'),
    path('mybox/<int:pk>/', views_api.MyBoxDetail.as_view(), name='mybox-detail'),
    path('mybox/<int:pk>/documents/', views_api.DocumentList.as_view(), name='mybox-document-list'),

    path('documents/', views_api.DocumentList.as_view(), name='document-list'),
    path('documents/<int:pk>/', views_api.DocumentDetail.as_view(), name='document-detail'),
```

My models.py:

```
class MyBox(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='boxes')
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, default='my_box')
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(_('time created'), auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def user_folder_doc_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/docs/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/docs/{1}'.format(instance.owner.id, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='documents')
    file = models.FileField(_('file'), upload_to=user_folder_doc_path, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(_('time created'), auto_now_add=True)
    mybox = models.ManyToManyField(MyBox, related_name='documents', blank=True)
```

My serializers:

```
class MyBoxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = MyBox
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'user', 'name', 'description', 'documents']

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    mybox = MyBoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'owner', 'description', 'file', 'mybox']
        extra_kwargs = {'mybox': {'required': False}}
```

And my views.py:

```
class DocumentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the documents
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        owner = self.request.user

        mybox_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        if mybox_id:
            return Document.objects.filter(mybox=mybox_id, owner=owner)
        else:
            return Document.objects.filter(owner=owner)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        mybox_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        if mybox_id:
            print("Hay ID de MyBox")
            mybox = MyBox.objects.get(pk=mybox_id)
            serializer = DocumentSerializer(data=self.request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                document = serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
                mybox.documents.add(document)
        else:
            print("No hay ID de MyBox")
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I've tried several suggestions I found online, with no luck. I believe the issue is my serializers, and I tried adding this to MyBoxSerializer: `documents = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='mybox-document-list', lookup_field='mybox_id')`

But I think I do not understand serializers enough when dealing with M2M relationships.

Just to reiterate, after going to mybox/1/documents/ and creating a new document here, the document gets properly created and the relationship with MyBox id:1 (in this example) is also there, but I never get a response, only the exception

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to fix the issue, thanks to the solution provided by somebody else. In case anyone gets to this page with a similar issue.

The problem was in the perform_create function, which had a serializer too many and I had to save the document too. This is the correct version that works for me:

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        mybox_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        if mybox_id:
            mybox = MyBox.objects.get(pk=mybox_id)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                document = serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
                document.mybox.add(mybox)
                document.save()
        else:
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I hope this helps